# How with calebporzio/sushi plugin fill data from other tables?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-sushi

On Laravel/filament site I need using solutionforest/filament-tree pluging to create custom tree
based on 3 tables
tasks :
=>tikets (has task_id field)
=>ticket_user (user assigned to any tickets)

I make it with calebporzio/sushi plugin and reading docts at https://github.com/calebporzio/sushi I created TaskTicketReport model, which I want to fill with data
at runtime :

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TaskTicketReport extends Model
{
    use \Sushi\Sushi;

    protected $rows
        = [
            [
                'id' => 1,
                'parent_id' => 0,
                'title' => '1 : Mastering Laravel/vue.js',
            ],
            [
                'id' => 2,
                'parent_id' => 0,
                'title' => '2 : Develop Tasks management site using Laravel/vue.js',
            ],
        ];

    public function getRows()
    {
        return $this->rows;
    }
    public function addTaskTicketReport(array $rowArray)
    {
        $this->rows[] = $rowArray;
    }
}
```

And using this class:

```
$tasks = Task::getByActive(Task::STATUS_ACTIVE)
->orderBy('id', 'asc')
    ->get();
    
$newTaskTicketReport = new TaskTicketReport();
foreach ($tasks as $task) {
    $newTaskTicketReport->addTaskTicketReport(
        [
            'id' => $task->id,
            'parent_id' => 0,
            'title' => $task->title,
        ],
    );
}

$taskTicketReports                  = TaskTicketReport:://getByActive($this->checkOnlyActive)
    orderBy('id', 'asc')
    ->get();
echo print_r( $taskTicketReports->toArray(), true );
```

and result data are default rows in Model, not data from Task model, which I try to add to TaskTicketReport...

and what I see in sql tracing :

```
   SELECT * 
    FROM `tasks` 
    WHERE `status` = '1' 
    ORDER BY `id` asc
```

How  can I do it ?

```
"laravel/framework": "^9.52.10",
"filament/filament": "^2.17.49",
"filament/forms": "^2.17.49",
"calebporzio/sushi": "^2.4",
```

**Quotation from the docs :**

```
Using ->getRows()

You can optionally opt out of using the protected $rows property, and directly implement your own getRows() method.

This will allow you to determine the rows for the model at runtime. You can even generate the model's rows from an external source like a third-party API.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sushi isn't made for this. The data is static; `addTaskTicketReport` won't save data, it'll be gone on the next pageview.

Comment: PLease read Quotation from the docs. I suppose that is possible.

Comment: You can generate the rows *for the current request*, but they'll all be gone for the next request.

Comment: But all my code is withing 1 request, I use console command for easy testing... Does it matter ?

Comment: Are there some different plugins/decisions for my goal?